# SCP on crontab still asking passphrase after key exchange

Tags: ssh, cron, scp

I need to perform "SCP" command in a `crontab` without entering passphrase.
So I have created the key

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Then transferred the `id_rsa.pub` file to `host_dest`.

After, copied the contents of `id_rsa.pub` to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

```
$ cat id_rsa.pub >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

If I try to perform an SCP, a passphrase is still required.

I also tried using

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

But also in that case I need to enter the passphrase.
Any suggestion?!?

Comment: Is enabled the PubkeyAuthentication in the /etc/sshd_config file?

Comment: yep  PubkeyAuthentication yes    #AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: RSAAuthentication = yes?
https://security.stackexchange.com/a/71581

Comment: yep RSAAuthentication yes

Comment: I found this:
Your private key file (on the local machine) must be readable and writable only by you: rw-------, i.e. 600
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36687

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passphrase is not a password.

Your key is encrypted and unless you provide the passphrase, it will ask for it. Cronjob does not have access to your `ssh-agent` that is running inside of your session. You have two options:

- [Remote the passphrase from the key](https://superuser.com/questions/1004188/how-do-i-remove-passphrase-authentification-on-freebsd-ssh/1004265#1004265) -- it will be less secure, but simpler to automate

  ```
  ssh-keygen -p -P old_passphrase -N "" -f /path/to/your.key
  ```
- Use `sshpass` and provide the passphrase for the key on the command-line (it is not secure either to store the passphrase in plaintext).

Comment: How can I implement your first suggestion?